# How to find which rows have at least one non-null field in a subtable (one-to-many), and which rows have only null fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine I have an database which has:

- a table `post` containing post names
- a table `part` containing parts of the posts, with a primary key field linked to a post_id (one-to-many)
- a table `comment` containing comments *for individual parts*, with a primay key field linked to a part_id (one-to-many)

So imagine querying:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
JOIN part ON post.id = part.post_id
JOIN comment ON part.id = comment.part_id
```

we would get for example the result:

```
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| post.id | post.name | part.id | part.name | comment.id | comment.text |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 1       | travel    | 1       | spain     | 1          | nice         |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 1       | travel    | 2       | norway    | 2          | cold         |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 1       | travel    | 3       | itaia     |            |              |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 2       | food      | 4       | cheese    | 3          | creamy       |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 2       | food      | 5       | pasta     |            |              |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 3       | sports    |         |           |            |              |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
| 4       | movies    | 6       | action    |            |              |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|------------|--------------|
```

And what i want to query is a list containing each `post name`, and their `number of comments`. So for the example below, i would like a query returning:

```
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| post.id | post.name | nb of comments |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 1       | travel    | 2              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 2       | food      | 1              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 3       | sports    | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 4       | movies    | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
```

For now, the query i have is made of 2 parts, first we find all the `posts` that have `comments`, and we `UNION` with another query that finds all the `posts` where `comment.id IS NULL`, but the problem is that sometimes there are some `posts` that have a `part`, but no `comment`, so the `comment` will still be `NULL`, and the second query will still return a row, while it does have at least one comment. Resulting on duplicate post.name rows.

My query:

```
SELECT post.id, post.name, count(*)
FROM post
JOIN part ON post.id = part.post_id
JOIN comment ON part.id = comment.part_id
GROUP BY post.name, post.part_id
UNION
SELECT post.id, post.name, NULL AS "count"
FROM post
LEFT JOIN part ON post.id = part.post_id
LEFT JOIN comment ON part.id = comment.part_id
WHERE comment.id IS NULL
GROUP BY post.name, post.part_id
ORDER BY name
```

This query would incorrectly return:

```
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| post.id | post.name | nb of comments |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 1       | travel    | 2              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 1       | travel    | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 2       | food      | 1              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 2       | food      | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 3       | sports    | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 4       | movies    | 0              |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
```

(see the duplicate travel and food rows)

How would I please get the expected result?

Comment: Your example output says `post.id`, but your example query uses `post.part_id`, which according to your description should not even exist.

Comment: yes indeed! mistake on my part, i changed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `left join`:

```
SELECT po.part_id, po.name, COUNT(c.part_id)
FROM post po LEFT JOIN
     part pa
     ON po.id = pa.post_id LEFT JOIN
     comment c
     ON pa.id = c.part_id
GROUP BY po.name, po.part_id;
```

Comment: I believe you want to use `COALESCE` rather than `NULLIF`.The OP *clearly* wants get 0, so it should read 'If you actually want the count as `0` rather than `NULL`, use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson . . . I am almost certain I saw `NULL` results when I answered the question (I would not have made up the `NULLIF()` part).  However, it is not shown in the edit history, so perhaps the OP changed it to zeros within 5 minutes.  Also, `COALESCE()` is *not* necessary.  `COUNT()` never returns `NULL` values.